# Как определить цепочку подключения к интернету?

Tags: сеть, eclipse, maven, proxy

Мой рабочий компьютер подключен к интернету, но не напрямую.

Меня не беспокоит запрет на посещение одноклассников и прочих ресурсов, но проблема в том, что я не могу подключить maven/gradle dependecies, скачать плагин для eclipse из marketplace.

Насколько я видел для maven можно настроить proxy, но как-бы мне узнать данные подключения для этой настройки?

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что раз это рабочий компьютер, у Вас на работе есть админ, который этим заведует. Он скорее всего закрыл все посторонние порты. Соответственно Вам надо выяснить какой порт использует Maven и попросить админа открыть этот порт для Вас. Никаких прокси городить, я думаю, не надо.