# Как выяснить какой порт использует Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven

С точки зрения ответа Dejsving на мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715887/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83) мне требуется выяснить какой порт используется Maven'ом, желательно также узнать какой порт использует Eclipse при закачке плагинов с marcketplace.

Сама проблема:

Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out  pom.xml /TestMavenProject   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem

UPD: line 1 на всякий случай

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Вы используете прокси, судя по всему?
Ответа на Ваш вопрос формально я дать не могу, т.к. точно не знаю, но предположу, что для загрузки по HTTP используется стандартный 80-й порт. Сам пользуюсь сейчас ant через прокси, достаточно было прописать инициализацию в build.xml и всё заработало, а на прокси открыт только 80-й порт.

Comment: Добавлю. Прошёл по ссылке на Ваш предыдущий вопрос. 
Судя по всему, дело не в закрытом порте, а в том, что сам maven не настроен на работу с прокси. 
Адрес прокси-сервера, полагаю, Вы можете узнать у своего администратора.
Информация о настройке maven для работы через прокси есть в официальной документации: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это поможет (2 ответ, т.к. по 80-му порту я спокойно серфю интернет) Но если есть возможность самому узнать адрес прокси-сервера, то хотелось бы знать и о ней)